# Deploying a Django Application (Apache, Passenger, Virtualenv)

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv, passenger

Im stuck in deploying my working Django Application on a production PLESK server. 
The project can be started as a development server successfully by typing:

```
httpdocs# cd mysite
httpdocs/mysite# source myvenv/bin/activate
httpdocs/mysite# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
httpdocs/mysite# python manage.py runserver <freyt.de>:8000
```

Then, if I point the browser to freyt.de:8000 I can see my app. Fine.
Right now, I'm trying to call my app by Passenger from Apache. When checking with "passenger-config restart-app" it seems to run, but when curl freyt.de it shows me html with 403 Forbidden. So, I assume my Django app is not started successfully.

This is my current folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

I already adjusted some topics in PLESK as follows:

- Apache Webserver: wsgi is activated
- I created a Service Plan and subscribed it with my domain freyt.de
- In the Service Plan under tab "Webserver" I added additional directives for HTTP as follows.

```
PassengerEnabled On
PassengerAppType wsgi
PassengerStartupFile passenger_wsgi.py
```

- In the Service Plan under "Hosting Parameters" I enabled SSH access to the server shell: /bin/bash
- For the "Domain" I set the Document root to "..httpdocs/public". Also I added in "Apache & nginx Settings" the same directives. (I also tried without, but dont seem to have an effect.)

Some details at Document Root:

- I added .htaccess in public with again same directives (just for testing). No other files in public.
- My passenger_wsgi.py contains, which seems to be ok:

```
import sys, os
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append(cwd + '/mysite')

if sys.version < "2.7.9":
  os.execl(cwd + "/mysite/myvenv/bin/python", "python3.6", *sys.argv)

sys.path.insert(0, cwd + '/mysite/myvenv/bin')
sys.path.insert(0, cwd + '/mysite/myvenv/lib/python3.6')
#sys.path.insert(0, cwd + '/mysite/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django')
sys.path.insert(0, cwd + '/mysite/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "mysite.settings"
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

- The file mysite/mysite/wsgi.py is untouched:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Would be great, if someone could point me in the correct direction. I think its just a small mistake somewhere :-) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey there....for anyone who might run into the same issue. I figured it out by myself:

- I deleted .htaccess file in public folder 

- In Plesk I changed the additional directives for HTTP as follows:

    ```PassengerEnabled On
     PassengerUser {username} ```

{username} is the user, which owns the root directory of the domain. You can check which user to be used by ls -l. 

Good luck

Comment: Unfortunately Im not allowed to post answers...Why not?